# Problema al crear una tabla en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, backend

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Oracle que me han mandado en clase y tengo un problema con la última tabla os comparto la imagen del modelo Entidad - relación del ejercicio y las órdenes de la creación de tablas, no se si se me estará escapando algo pero por más que lo he estado revisando no encuentro el posible fallo que tenga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí os comparto el código de como he creado las tablas.

Tabla Oficina:

```
CREATE TABLE OFICINA (
OFICINA NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_OFICINA PRIMARY KEY,
CIUDAD VARCHAR2 (20),
REGION VARCHAR2 (25),
DIR VARCHAR2 (30),
OBJETIVO VARCHAR2 (25),
VENTAS VARCHAR2 (10)
);
```

Tabla Empleado:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADO (
NUMEMP NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLEADO PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2 (15), 
EDAD NUMBER (3),
OFICINA NUMBER,
TITULO VARCHAR2 (15),
FECHACONTRATADO DATE,
JEFE NUMBER,
CUOTA VARCHAR2 (20),
VENTAS VARCHAR2 (20),
CONSTRAINT FK_OFICINAEMPLEADO FOREIGN KEY(OFICINA) REFERENCES OFICINA (OFICINA),
 CONSTRAINT FK_JEFE_EMPLEADO FOREIGN KEY (JEFE) REFERENCES EMPLEADO (NUMEMP)
);
```

Tabla Cliente:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
NUMCLIENTE NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTE PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2 (20),
REPCLIENTE NUMBER,
LIMITECREDITO NUMBER (25),
CONSTRAINT FK_REPCLIENTE FOREIGN KEY (REPCLIENTE) REFERENCES EMPLEADO (NUMEMP)
);
```

Tabla Producto:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO (
IDFAB NUMBER,
IDPRODUCTO NUMBER,
DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2 (30),
PRECIO NUMBER (5,2),
EXISTENCIAS NUMBER (4),
CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTO PRIMARY KEY (IDFAB, IDPRODUCTO)
);
```

Tabla Pedido:

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO (
CODIGO NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_PEDIDO PRIMARY KEY,
NUMPEDIDO NUMBER (9),
FECHAPEDIDO DATE,
CLIE NUMBER,
REP NUMBER,
FAB NUMBER,
PRODUCTO NUMBER,
CANT NUMBER (7),
IMPORTE NUMBER (7),
CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_PEDIDO FOREIGN KEY (CLIE) REFERENCES CLIENTE (NUMCLIENTE),
CONSTRAINT FK_REP_PEDIDO FOREIGN KEY (REP) REFERENCES EMPLEADO (NUMEMP),
CONSTRAINT FK_FAB_PEDIDO FOREIGN KEY (FAB) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (IDFAB),
CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTO_PEDIDO FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTO) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (IDPRODUCTO)
);
```

El error que me sale cuando doy a ejecutar para que se me cree la última tabla es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La llave primaria de productos es una llave compuesta, entonces la llave foránea de PEDIDO hacia PRODUCTO debería ser compuesta, es decir, en una sola restricción: `CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTO FOREIGN KEY(FAB,PRODUCTO) REFERENCES PRODUCTO(IDFAB, IDPRODUCTO)`.

Comment: @Sal Muchas gracias era eso, ya me dejo crear la tabla correctamente, me tenía desesperado eso y ya no sabía que hacer.